What scale do I need to consider when calculating a body condition index?
I'm trying to calculate a body condition index (scaled mass index [SMI]; Peig and Green 2009) for groups of frogs and I'm having trouble understanding what scale I need to consider when calculating a scaling exponent (bSMA). The equation for SMI is as follows:

where "Mi and Li are the body mass and the linear body measurement of individual 'i' respectively, bSMA is the scaling exponent estimated by the standard major axis regression of M on L; L0 is an arbitrary value of L (e.g. the arithmetic mean value for the study population); and Mˆi is the predicted body mass for individual i when the linear body measure is standardized to L0." - Peig and Green 2009
With this context in mind, I would like to do 2 things:

Compare the change in body condition between 2 groups of frogs (captive raised vs. pen raised) from the same population.
Compare SMI across 4 groups of frogs (group 1: release scenario 1 at Site 1, group 2: release scenario 2 at Site 1, group 3: release scenario 1 at site 2 and group 4: release scenario 2 at site 2) from 2 different populations (site 1 and site 2).

For the former question, I'm trying to understand how the holding type (raised in captivity vs raised in outdoor pens) affects body condition, and for the latter question, I'm trying to develop values so I can factor the body condition of frogs at the time of release into a survival model in case body condition might explain some of the variation in survival/movement of the frogs.
Do I need to calculate a single bSMA value for each analysis (so in this case, two)?
Or
do I need a separate bSMA value for each group (so in this case, six [2 for first question and 4 for second question])?
OR do I just need a separate bSMA value for each distinct population of frogs (so in this case, two)?
I'm confused at what scale I need to consider the bSMA value. The paper frames the equation in context of a single study population, but my first question considers frogs in only population 1 while my second question considers frogs in population 1 and 2.
Any insight is appreciated.

There's definitely a statistical aspect to this, but it seems like we would need expertise in your specific sub-field to answer this well.

I don't know your sample size, but my experience with calculating SMI for frogs says that for both cases I'd calculate a single estimate of bSMA. This is because the larger the sampling points in the major axis regression, the better the estimate of the slope. This is what matters in the end.

Thank you, Diogo. Since they are all the same species of frog I agree with your suggestion and will try it out.
